# Existence of $x$ so $x>y_i$ for $y_i$ in $y_0<y_1< \ldots$

Tags: limits, logic

There is a real number $x$ and we can prove that $x>y_i$ for all $i$ where $y_i$ in an increasing sequence $y_0<y_1<y_2< \ldots$

Can we imply that such $x$ doesn't exist from this?

Comment: It depends on what you mean.  The sequence $y$ is coming out of nowhere.  Are you saying you have an undescribed sequence with a putative $x$ with this property? Or that there exists a sequence such that there exists an $x$ with this property? Or that for any sequence you can find and $x$ with this property? Or given the $x$ every sequence has this property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated, the answer is "no, we can't infer that such $x$ doesn't exist". It depends on the sequence.

Let $y_i = 1-\frac{1}{i}$. Then $x=1$ works.

Let $y_i = i$. Then there is no such $x$.